# How to pass meta information in scrapy parse?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to debug my spider using `scrapy parse` as described in the [official documentation](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html)

However the parsing method I want to debug expects that the request contains some meta information( `Request(url, meta={.....})`  ).

How can I specify that my Request should carry this information when using the `scrapy parse` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the source code of the parse command, I found that it is not possible and filed an enhancement request:

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1046

UPDATE

It is now possible, see this [pull request](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2957)